# how to make descending by price display shopping cart in opencart

Tags: opencart

i just want to ask what are the codes in catalog folder does i need to open if i want to descending the list of products that i added in the shopping cart in opencart. for example, i have three (3) products, product A = $3.00, product B = $2.75 and product c = $1.50,

I have tried to look and add an **ORDER BY price DESC** in $product_query at the cart.php **(\system\library\cart.php)** but I failed to order by the lists of products present in the shopping cart.

is there a solution that can I descend the lists of product in the shopping cart? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the PHP commands you need to be focussed on for OpenCart
Found in the **/catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php**

```
if ($this->cart->hasProducts() || (isset($this->session->data['vouchers']) && $this->session->data['vouchers'])) { // look for hasProducts

$products = $this->cart->getProducts(); // look for this
```

The files are also in

```
system/library/cart.php
system/library/product.php
```

You need to edit `public function getProducts() {`

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id)";
```

There are some more edits, just do a find in folder for those functions in the OpenCart zip. You can add your `ORDER BY` and other functions within these SQL commands. I would advise downloading a OpenCart version that matches yours and keep the zip extracted - never touch the source so you can refer back to it, always save original work as .bk or .php.backup or .compress if using WordCompress

## Update

Not all the files are structured in the MVC format. Some files are in the system folders and some files and functions have been combined.

Comment: No worries please mark this as your answer if this has helped.